# How to rawQuery in multiple columns in Sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqlite, sqflite

I created an onChanged function for a TextFormField to perform a query in multiple columns of a table. I tried to use OR in the WHERE clause, but it does not seem to work since it only returns queries from the first condition (columnOne), and not when I search for items from columnTwo or columnThree. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

```
onChanged: (String? databaseQuery) async {
   Database db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;
   List<Map> result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnOne LIKE ? OR columnTwo LIKE ? OR columnThree LIKE ?', ['%$databaseQuery%']);
   _map = result;
   setState(() {});
}
```

Note: What I am trying to accomplish is like a Full Text Search, but I want to do it via rawQuery or query only instead of having to enable FTS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for each ? in the raw Query, you need also a argument

```
List<Map> result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnOne LIKE ? OR columnTwo LIKE ? OR columnThree LIKE ?', ['%$databaseQuery%', '%$databaseQuery%', '%$databaseQuery%']);
```